# How should i use if else and for loop with .hbs file (Handlebars.js)?

Tags: handlebars.js, ejs

I know how can i use if else statement or for loop using .ejs file but i need to change code in .hbs file and i am new with this.Please help me with below example in which i have used .ejs file i need to convert it in .hbs file but don't know how to change if else and for loop

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Fetch using MySQL and Node.js</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="table-data">
<h2>Display Data using Node.js & MySQL</h2>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>S.N</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Edit</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
        
        <%
        if(userData.length!=0){
        var i=1;
        userData.forEach(function(data){
        %>
        <tr>
            <td><%=i; %></td>
            <td><%=data.fullName %></td>
            <td><%=data.emailAddress %></td>
            <td><%=data.city %></td>
            <td><%=data.country %></td>
            <td><a href="/users/edit/<%=data.id%>">Edit</a></td>
            <td><a href="/users/delete/<%=data.id%>">Delete</a></td>
        </tr>
        <%  i++; }) %>
        <% } else{ %>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">No Data Found</td>
            </tr>
        <% } %>
    </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I have used below code but it is not working as i am new i need your guidence

````
@76484 i have used this ``` {{#if userData.length != 0 }}
{{var i =1;}}
{{userData.forEach(function(data))}}
<tr>
            <td>{{=i;}}</td>
            <td>{{= data.fullName}}</td>
            <td>{{= data.emailAddress}}</td>
            <td>{{= data.city}}</td>
            <td>{{= data.country}}</td>
            <td>{{= data.Dimension_4_Score}}</td>
            <td>{{= data.Total_Score_Persentage}}</td>
            
        </tr>
        {{i++; })}}  
       {{else{} }  
            <tr>
                <td colspan="7">No Data Found</td>
            </tr>
        {{}}}  
        </table>
        </div>
      </body> ``` but it is not working
````

Comment: This is very achievable with basic Handlebars functionality (`#if`, `#each`). What have you tried?

Comment: @76484 i have updated the code (in question) what i did ... i am new in hbs ... so i need help my code is not working and giving error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The primary difference between your embedded JS example and Handlebars is that Handlebars *does not* execute arbitrary JavaScript, like your `.forEach` loop. Instead, Handlebars provides [helpers](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html) to allow you to do things like conditionals and iteration.

First, we will tackle your condition, `if (userData.length != 0)`. Handlebars has a [`#if` helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#if) which we could use to check if `userData` has a truth (greater than 0) `length`. The result would be:

```
{{#if userData.length}}
    {{! TODO: output each user data}}
{{else}}
    <tr>
        <td colspan="7">No Data Found</td>
    </tr>
{{/if}}
```

Secondly, Handlebars has an [`#each` helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html#each) which is used for looping over collections as you are doing with your `userData.forEach(function(data) { /*...*/ }` code. For your purposes, the syntax would be:

```
{{#each userData}}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ @index }}</td>
        <td>{{ fullName }}</td>
        <td>{{ emailAddress }}</td>
        <td>{{ city }}</td>
        <td>{{ country }}</td>
        <td><a href="/users/edit/{{ id }}">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="/users/delete/{{ id }}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
{{/each}}
```

Notice how we are evaluating the properties of each object in our `userData` array. There is no `=`. We just wrap the property name in double-handlebars, like `{{ fullName }}`. Handlebars handles the execution context within the `#each` so that we are always referring to the current iteration of our array.

Also notice the `{{ @index }}`. This is a [special variable](https://handlebarsjs.com/api-reference/data-variables.html#index) provided by Handlebars to give us the current iteration index within our `#each` loop. It is zero-index, so our output will be slightly different from your ejs example because you initialized your counter at 1.

Unfortunately, if we want our indexes to be one-based, we will have to write a [custom helper](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#custom-helpers) to this. Our helper would just need to take a number, `@index`, and increment it by 1. It would look like:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('increment', function (num) {
    return num + 1;
});
```

And we would update our template to make use of it:

```
{{increment @index }}
```

I have created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/76484/dknm0t9f/) with the final example for your reference.